# Generic types. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

I have the following structure of my code :

```
public interface ICode { }

public interface IPreparedCode<TCode>
    where TCode : ICode { }

public interface ILayer<TPreparedCode>
    where TPreparedCode : IPreparedCode<ICode> { }

public interface IContext<TCode, TPreparedCode, TLayer>
    where TCode : ICode
    where TPreparedCode : IPreparedCode<TCode>
    where TLayer : ILayer<TPreparedCode> { }
```

and i have error "There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from TPreparedCode to IPreparedCode<ICode>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic parameter for `ILayer` is constrained to be `IPreparedCode<ICode>`, but the generic parameter you are giving it, is `TPreparedCode`, which is constrained to `IPreparedCode<TCode>`. Notice the difference? `IPreparedCode<TCode>` can't be converted to `IPreparedCode<ICode>`.

To fix this, you can add an extra generic parameter `TCode` to `ILayer`, and constrain `TPreparedCode` to `IPreparedCode<TCode>` instead.:

```
public interface ICode { }

public interface IPreparedCode<TCode>
    where TCode : ICode { }

public interface ILayer<TPreparedCode, TCode>
    where TCode : ICode
    where TPreparedCode : IPreparedCode<TCode> { }

public interface IContext<TCode, TPreparedCode, TLayer>
    where TCode : ICode
    where TPreparedCode : IPreparedCode<TCode>
    where TLayer : ILayer<TPreparedCode, TCode> { }
```

Comment: But `TCode` is `ICode` then `IPreparedCode<TCode>` equals `IPreparedCode<ICode>`. Maybe i demand too much =D

Comment: @HHHack Okay, let's go one step back. Do you agree that a `List<string>` can't be assigned to a variable of type `List<object>`?

Comment: @ Sweeper It is possible, but need use covariance.